# How to remove only one provider from UserOAuthProviders

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-auth

To associate social providers to the user account, we can simply use `api/auth/facebook` and I could also find that using `auth/logout` would logout the user...

in the database, 2 profiles are still there, so logout is a simple way to kill the auth session... but how can I unlink them?

- Is there a way to, using the API, just remove/unlink the account to one social login?

[image]

---

**NOTE:**
<del>I got here when I added `/Friends/Index.cshtml` View (without a controller) as the social logins started to work "out-of-the-blue"... I did not find anything in the docs regarding this, might be a good idea to have such important note :)</del>

this is done with `oauth.<provider>.CallbackUrl` on `web.config`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not an explicit API for deleting UserAuth records, but you can just use OrmLite and the [UserAuth POCO's](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/UserAuth.cs) to delete them as you wish, e.g you can remove twitter provider record with:

```
Db.Delete<UserOAuthProviders>(q => 
    q.UserAuthId == 5 && q.Provider == "twitter");
```

The default behavior of the AuthProviders is that when logging into existing AuthProviders when you're already authenticated will link them to the same account. To have each login create separate accounts (i.e. new UserAuth entry) you want to `/logout` first.

Comment: Thank you! I'm starting to be a big fan of SS and all thank to you, you can count me in as a faithful version 4 "payer developer" and I hope to contribute to all the work you've done so far! :)

Comment: np :) glad you're enjoying it!